# weird Ajax ComboBox drop down list

Tags: asp.net, ajax, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got combobox inside some panel :

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox 
    ID="YearList" 
    runat="server" 
    OnInit="YearList_Init1" 
    EnableTheming="false" 
    Width="45px"
    ViewStateMode="Disabled" />
```

and it was OK before I updated project to .NET 4 , after updating project (And AJAX) to .net4 it's looking like really strange ... I can't explain it proper , I will show :
[image]

how can I fix it ? :) Full CSS / ASPX page here -> https://github.com/nCdy/Issues/tree/master/Ajax%20ComboBox (string # 287)

Comment: Try to change behavior with ListItemHoverCssClass="ComboBoxListItemHover" property.

Comment: It would be better if you could host this somewhere so people could debug the css

Comment: @Hawxby Project is very complex, got many depends and hard database. I can host this page and css. Going to do it.

Comment: @Hawxby updated first question with it.

Comment: I have a similar problem, couldnt figure out a solution yet and my code isn't localized anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and could resolve mine by removing the extender that I had added to the Panel containing the combobox. I had used a DropShadowExtender for the Panel, removing it caused the combobox to be displayed perfectly. Perhaps you can try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

i am seeing a lot of texts like

```
&#1050;&#1086;&#1085;&#1090;&#1088;&#1072;&#1082;&#1090;&#1085;&#1099;&#1081; &#1095;&#1072;&#1089;
                                    :&nbsp;
```

, every where in your form. So i need to know, are you using some sort of encoding , that is, is this placed by you or came unexpectedly. If you havent placed it, remove all unneccessary such lines and use plain text instead (if required). Then check the layout.

*Also in your image, i can see , ur language is russian(if i am right :)). So try using your localized font that is direcly supported by aspx as we use english or better use resource file instead of the hardcoded text on the page. As per my view the language conversion is creating such issue.*

Comment: That is Russian ... I really have no idea if I can store this text as normal text. after all , what do you think about ajax trouble ?