# Ajax update panel - how to set max updating time?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

That isn't usual for my WebApplication, but user can load really long process inside UpdatePanel.

And he will wait it looking on loading via UpdateProcessing stuff.

The trouble is because **Update Panel Aborts loading after some time** and totally breaking web application.

How can I calm down this Ajax control ?

*offtopic : another ajax trouble when I even didn't fixed the* [trouble with their ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485153/weird-ajax-combobox-drop-down-list)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET UpdatePanel Time Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158975/asp-net-updatepanel-time-out)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Script manager, set the AsyncPostBackTimeout. The value should be in seconds. For example:

```
AsyncPostBackTimeout = "600"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbacktimeout.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.NET UpdatePanel Time Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158975/asp-net-updatepanel-time-out)